# See which user installed a plugin?

Tags: plugins, admin

Are there any DB entries made when a plugin is installed, and if so does this indicate which user did so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, natively WordPress doesn't audit and store any records of admin activity.

Retroactively the best you can do is try to get relevant information from web server access logs.

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, are there any plugins which do this sort of thing? Or is it possible it may be added in core?

Comment: @javy sure are, see [Stream](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stream/) for example :)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress itself does not keep the information.

You need to install an audit plugin like [WP Admin Audit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-admin-audit/) (or one of [the other option](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/activity-log/)s).

Only the actions (like plugin installations) from that moment on will be tracked.
Actions done prior to the installation of the audit plugin will not be available.